# Adding files of github to your project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I found at github an interesting menu featuring. and I would like to add it to your project in xcode.How can I do that?there a very large number files ,how to find out what files you need to download or add to that exist in xcode files?

Comment: It depends on the project, at least post the code to the github repository

Comment: in my case need to download.for example this https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu

Comment: You could use CocoaPods for example (if available for the project your found), or Carthage maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways

1. Download: download the code and add the .h & .m files to your project
2. [Sub-module](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule): add it as sub-module to your repository and add the .h and .m files to your project
3. [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org): this is an automatic build system like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) for Java, which used to include other projects into your project in case the repository supports it

Cocoapods is the best way in case the repository supports it which I think it will be the case for the most famous components

Comment: What's the difference if  i add file .h and .m to my project or use coocapods?

Comment: Cocoapods automatically adds the repository to a project called pod and link that project with your original project, and you can maintain the repository version in the podfile. It has the advantage of not adding other files to your repository, you just need to track your own files beside the podfile. In case of adding .h & .m files your will need to change it latter your self to update the used library and you will need to track it on your gut repository which adds noise to your commits

Comment: why exactly workspase?Why not add as a subproject in my.projeckt and  open .xcodeprojeckt? There is a difference if you use them as in the  subproject?